# Uploads to wiki directory fail from form on Special:Uploads page

Tags: file-uploads, wiki

I'm using the default wiki theme and can't get file uploads to work from the Special:Uploads page. The form allows me to select a file, submit the form, (no error is thrown), but the file does not appear in the directory or the Special:Files page. I'm logged into EE as Super Admin.

The directory is writable from within CP. (It uses the same preferences as my other working directories). If I upload a file through the CP it still does not appear in Special:Files.

EE 2.8.1